# Live Images are showing on offline(no internet) mode too - Ionic 3 App

Tags: android, image, caching, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using [**this cache API**](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache) to cache the content on the page.All are working fine.But when I disconnected the internet on the mobile device, I can see all the image content too on the cached page.Those images are coming from AWS and having a path like below.When I debugged the offline use case, the URLs are same as below.In other words, I didn't put any special effort to cache the images.So my question is, how those images are showing on offline use case? You can see that according to the image URLs it must work only on the online use case.So how this works? Hope you'll give a feedback for this.

**Update:**

By disconnect means: disconnecting from the internet with the app open

**Use case:**

I have an online page(i.e. working only with the internet) where the user can select the content for the offline(i.e. no internet) reading.What I have done here is, I have cached the content and then use that already cached content on the offline page.But I didn't put any special effort to cache the images.As I mentioned above I can see the live URLs on the images on the offline page too.But still, those images are shown on that offline page.Any clue, please?

***This is the image URL on offline page too:***

```
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blue/pic/my-thumbnail-136x200-95.jpg">
```

Comment: By disconnect do you mean discconecting from internet with the app open or do you close/kill your app, discconect and then open the app? And if you're in a page that already opened an image, discconect and then go to another page (for the first time) that has an image, does it load?

Comment: Please see the updated content on my post above @GabrielBarreto

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this caching service neither have came across this behaviour, but here's what i can share:

I have an app where I show an avatar in some pages, it's a Firebase image and the link is always the same. When i open the image, disconnect and go to a page where i have to show this image again it doesn't shows until i connect the internet again.

Since you're using Amazon AWS i don't know if it has the same behaviour, since you probably needs to authenticate to connect and retrieve the image, thus it needs internet to this.

My first guess is that since it's a single page app, when you open an image in a page, it's already downloaded and has a success request, then when you navigate to another page it's already cached in, not because of the cache service installed, but be cause it's opened in a early page on your stack.

If you close the app, kill/destroy it and open again the common behaviour is to fail to show an image, since you've not downloaded it again. If you do this and it shows the image it's beyond my knowledge.

It's not something on the cache service since you need to especify what you want to cache and you're using it directly on your HTML page.

So my second guess is that AWS does something, since Firebase has a behaviour for working with its images, AWS must have it's own way to work with it. So it automatically caches the opened image and creates some sort of indexing or reference so it can first look for success calls to that image before calling the API again (i've never worked with AWS and never looked at it's docs, so i'm just saying what i think).

This answer is more like a comment that is too long for the comment box, but i hope it can give you some ideas of where to look for the correct answer.

Comment: I have closed the app (i.e. removed from the background) and open a fresh copy.It shows images without any issue.But I must say this, It happens only on the cached page.All other images on other online pages are not showing at all.Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't need any authenticate to connect and retrieve the images.All are public images just now.

Comment: @Sampath nice to know, i've got curious about this and will try the cache service and see if i can find something. If you find anything please share :)

Comment: Great.Please try that cache service and let me know.I just used this simple cache service (i.e. `Cache classic data`) on that API. https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache#cache-classic-data-arrays-objects-strings-numbers-etc